# How to draw separate lines on matplotlib for 3D plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have three variables:

```
xs = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
ys = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 
zs = [1,4,9,2,8,18,4,16,36]
```

I want to plot a graph with 3 separate lines by fixing a xs e.g. say for x = 2 I want to see the line of ys and zs (where x = 2) which should be `ys = [1,2,3], zs = [2,8,18]` in this case. I want to be able to see a different line for each unique x in xs but within the same plot. Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

I've tried doing it just using `ax.plot3D(xs,ys,zs)` but as you would expect it connects the points so that it's one continuous 3d line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use numpy arrays, you can use `np.where` to get the indices where every unique X value appears. Then use these indices to slice `xs`, `ys` and `zs` on each `ax.plot3D` call:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create numpy arrays
xs = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3])
ys = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3])
zs = np.array([1,4,9,2,8,18,4,16,36])

# Create Figure and 3D Axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

# Iterate over unique values in xs array
for unique_x in np.unique(xs):
    # Slice arrays and plot
    xvals = xs[np.where(xs == unique_x)]
    yvals = ys[np.where(xs == unique_x)]
    zvals = zs[np.where(xs == unique_x)]
    ax.plot3D(xvals, yvals, zvals)

# Display Figure
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]